# height:auto not working properly, div doesn't expand with content

Tags: css, height

I ran into a problem, while creating a column for messages on my website. Probably every message will be different lengths, so the divs' height contains them should be automatic. Somehow it is not working. Could you please tell me, which part of my code causes the problem? The container div doesn't expand with the content.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pbqL0oyu/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.ConvoCol2 {
width: 600px;
bottom:-50px;
position:absolute;
/*max-height:98vh;*/
margin-left: 0px;
height:91.95vh;
background-color:white;
display:inline-block;
padding-bottom:100px;}

.Typer {
width: 600px;
bottom:0px;
position:absolute;
/*max-height:98vh;*/
left: 0px;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
z-index:2;
padding-bottom:100px;}

.messageblock {
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
width: 600px;
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
min-height: 20px;
height:auto;}

.messageid {
left: 10px;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
}

.messageid p {
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 1em;
top: -15px;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
width: 200px;
font-weight:bold;
left: 65px;}

.msgcontent {
width: 560px;
font-family:Arial;
position:absolute;
left:30px;
top: 60px;
height:auto;
min-height: 30px;
word-wrap:break-word;}

.messageid img {
height:40px;
width:40px;
left: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
     <div class="ConvoCol2">
            <div class="messageblock">
                <div class="messageid">
                    <img src="https://scontent-a-vie.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/10849833_340959799423688_183902189805735256_n.jpg?oh=ea4fbcd056669d84e5459cd3918bf1c0&oe=550000F1" />
                    <p> Name Here</p>

                </div>
                <div class="msgcontent">
                   asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="Typer">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you need all the absolute positioning?

Comment: It seems the easiest way positioning my elements, since there is an other column on the left of it in the original code, i just didn't include it because it works well.

Comment: Found a solution: I replaced .msgcontent top and left property with margin-top and margin-left, now it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you use `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` it will be cut out and placed on a new layer (if you would compare it with how photoshop works), therefore your browser does not "know" the dimensions anymore and will simply give it 0 height when positioning the other elements. Or as @Terry commented:

> It will remove elements from the document flow/layout and will not
>   interfere with the positioning of other elements, or the dimensions of
>   their parent(s).

```
position:absolute;
left:30px;
top: 60px;
```

Can for example be replaced with:

```
margin-left:30px;
margin-top:60px;
```

Comment: Your answer is not entirely correct — using fixed or absolute positioning still allows proper dimension computation (height will not be zero, for example), but they will **remove elements from the document flow/layout** and will not interfere with the positioning of other elements, or the dimensions of their parent(s).

Comment: @Terry that's what I meant, but I guess I went too **w3schools** in my explanation in order to make it clear for the beginners.

Comment: Thank you, both of you :) Appreciated the details!